# Xamarin PCL Project crashes with exception for android but works perfectly for windows phone

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have created a Xamarin PCL application. I request to REST API and bind the data to a listview. It works properly in Windows phone. But crashes with an exception in android. The exception message is "An Unhandled Exception Occured!"

My code for the Xaml file and Xaml.cs file is as below.

**Xaml.Cs**

```
public class ItemClass
{
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
}

public partial class HomePageSingle : ContentPage
{
    private const string WebServiceUrl ="http://localhost:49452/api/Items/";

    public async void GetItemsAsync() 
    {
        //var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());

        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);

        List<ItemClass> taskModels =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemClass>>(json); 

        lstItems1.ItemsSource = taskModels;
    }


    public HomePageSingle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GetItemsAsync();
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="lstItems1">         
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label  Text="{Binding ItemCode}" TextColor="Black" />
                    <Label  Text="{Binding ItemDesc}" TextColor="Black"/> 
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

========================================================================

I put a try/catch and found out that the exception gets thrown not on my code but form the Resource.Designer.cs file. There is a function in that file as below:

public static void UpdateIdValues() 
{ 
global::ModernHttpClient.Resource.String.library_name = global::MyFirstDbApp.Droid.Resource.String.library_name; global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Resource.Attribute.ac‌​tionBarSize = global::MyFirstDbApp.Droid.Resource.Attribute.actionBarSize; 
}

My code loops into this function a few times and throws an Unhandled Exception. Unable to insert try/catch in there. 
Kindly help.

Comment: Check that your Android device/emulator has access to this Url: http://localhost:49452/api/Items/ it sounds to me it doesn't.

Comment: There is probably more to the exception message, please provide some more detail. As @apineda mentioned, check that you can reach the URL (from the emulator browser) also check that you have installed the NuGet package that contains the `NativeMessageHandler` class is installed on your Android project.

Comment: Sorry but How do I check if my android emulator has access to the url? I did not need to check anything like that for the windows though. Yes I have added the nuget package "modernhttpclient" for the NativeMessageHandler

Comment: Add a Try/Catch so you can take a look to stacktrace

Comment: Go into the emulator browser and try to reach the localhost URL. Or check if is has network/internet access at all by going to anything.

Comment: I did insert a try/catch and found out that the exception gets thrown not on my code but from the Resource.Desginer.cs file. I have added the code from where the exception gets thrown above on my question post.

Comment: My inernet access is working just fine. Its able to access websites using inernet. But my web api URL being unable to be accessed on the emulator. Kindly help.